# Detecting EEPROM data and address bus short circuit

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

Let us consider a microcontroller has an on-chip EEPROM and it is interfaced with micro through data and address buses.

Is there any way to check the short circuit conditions of the data and address buses?

Comment: That is not related to programming. (And: yes, there is - use an ohmmeter)

Comment: @Olaf - difficult for *on-chip* memory.   I presume he is referring to memory test patterns that deduce such faults.  Micheal Barr has [written on this subject](http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/miscellaneous/software-based-memory-testing.html) more extensively that could reasonably be posted here.

Comment: If it is memory mapped (not always the case for EEPROM), then it makes no difference whether the memory technology is EEPROM, SRAM, flash, SDRAM, FRAM or whatever.

Comment: @Clifford: right. did overlook this. But how come there would be a short actually? A chip-vendor should have his own testing facilities and there are  seniors to ask. OTOH "... and its interfaced with **micro** .." Micro what if on-chip it is part of "micro". I still suspect I'm right and he means "on-board".

Comment: Could you please clarify if that is on-chip or on-board? Also please state if how that is related to software and what the specific problem is.

Comment: Moreover, *off-chip* parallel EEPROM (with address and data buses) are increasingly uncommon compared with serial devices.  The low speed and density of EEPROM is such that having a parallel bus is hardly worth the increased pin count, device size and board space.

Comment: @Clifford: Forget it. He seems to have lost interest anyway. (But, yes, you are right, That's why I was surprised. Most EEPROMs nowwadays are 24*XX I2C types or - possibly SPI. Bot for both, the question makes even less no sense.

Comment: To allow for different time-zones and the fact that people do often have to sleep and work I generally allow 24 hours before writing someone off as disinterested.

Comment: @Clifford to clarify the question more i would like to add that this is an on-chip eeprom, not an on-board.what i wanted to specifically ask was whether we can detect this issue using the software logic,not through any hardware means.my understanding is in case the two buses are shorted,if you transmit something on data bus and same is reflected on address bus,there may be a chance of short circuit.so for that we need to monitor the internal buses through a software logic.But i could not think of one.

Comment: @ashiskumarmishra :  That's useful information, but it was Olaf that requested it not me.  The Michael Barr link I posted in a comment probably covers your requirement.  Note however that any test will be destructive of stored data.

Comment: Not to mention that parallel external address buses and memories are historically rather error-prone and vulnerable to EMC. This technique is pretty much considered obsolete nowadays, it was getting phased out in the late 1990s/ early 2000s when internal flash memories became mainstream for MCUs.

Comment: thanks all for your valuable comments.

Comment: @Clifford I referred the doc that you mentioned and it was helpful.also wanna thank Olaf,Lundin for your inputs

Comment: If the internal bus is shorted, it is highly likely that the chip is damaged in ways that are likely to prevent any software from running at all.  The address/data bus to the EEPROM is probably the same bus used for all other memory access.